# How can I Find the Largest Prime Value in a Dictionary of ASCII Sums?

Tags: python, dictionary, ascii, primes

I'm working on a Python script that reads a text file, splits it into a list of strings, and calculates the sum of ASCII values for each string. I've stored this data in a dictionary where the strings are the keys and the ASCII sums are the values. Now, I need help finding the largest prime value from this dictionary. Any suggestions or code examples would be greatly appreciated!

```
if __name__ == "__main":
    # Opening the file in read mode with all words in a txt file 
    my_file = open("english FILTERED.ALL.txt", "r") 

    # Reading the file 
    data = my_file.read() 

    # Replacing and splitting the text when newline ('\n') is seen. 
    data_into_list = data.split("\n") 
    print(data_into_list) 
    my_file.close() 

    # Create a dictionary to store the list values and the ASCII values with them
    result_dict = {}

    # Loop through the list and calculate the sum of ASCII values for each string
    for x in data_into_list:
        ascii_sum = sum(ord(char) for char in x)
        result_dict[x] = ascii_sum

    # Printing the original list
    print("The original list: " + str(data_into_list))

    # Printing the dictionary containing string-sum pairs
    print("String and their ASCII sum: " + str(result_dict))
```

I have successfully calculated the sum of ASCII values for each string and stored them in a dictionary. However, I'm now trying to find the largest prime value among these sums.

Here is currently an example of my current output

```
String and their ASCII sum : {'ACM': 209, 'ANSI': 299, 'ASAP': 293, 'ASCII': 361, 'Achilles': 805, 'Ada': 262, 'Afghanistan': 1124, 'Africa': 582, 'African': 692, 'Africans': 807, 'Airedale': 791, 'Alabama': 671, 'Alabamian': 886, 'Alaska': 589, 'Albania': 680, 'Albanian': 790, 'Albanians': 905, 'Alcibiades': 993, 'Alden': 484, 'Algeria': 693}
```

I'm seeking guidance on how to efficiently identify the largest prime value from a dictionary of ASCII sums, as I want to find the largest prime ASCII sum in my dictionary.

Comment: What is your actual question?  How to know if a number is prime?

Comment: @JohnGordon I want to find the largest prime value in my dictionary. There are many more words I just posted a few words and the sum of their ascci values for a partial output.

Comment: So you have a sequence of numbers, and you want to find the largest prime out of those.  What is the actual difficulty here?  What is your **actual question**?  It seems to me like your actual **specific programming question** is "How do I tell if a given number is prime?"

Comment: The steps to solving this are: 1. Sort the numbers in reverse order (i.e. largest first).  2. Iterate over the numbers.  3. Stop when you find a prime.  So, which of those steps do you not know how to do?

Comment: The challenge I'm currently tackling is the efficient identification of the largest prime value within this sequence. I'm in search of effective code to navigate through the dictionary and find and return the largest prime value to solve this task @JohnGordon

Comment: I just told you the **exact steps** you need to perform this task.  Which of those steps are you having trouble with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is_prime function implemented to call. Iterating on the dictionary that u created, and it finds the largest prime number.

**Sample Code:**

```
def is_prime(n):
    if n <= 1:
        return False
    if n <= 3:
        return True
    if n % 2 == 0 or n % 3 == 0:
        return False
    i = 5
    while i * i <= n:
        if n % i == 0 or n % (i + 2) == 0:
            return False
        i += 6
    return True

result_dict = {'ACM': 209, 'ANSI': 299, 'ASAP': 293, 'ASCII': 361, 'Achilles': 805, 'Ada': 262, 'Afghanistan': 1124, 'Africa': 582, 'African': 692, 'Africans': 807, 'Airedale': 791, 'Alabama': 671, 'Alabamian': 886, 'Alaska': 589, 'Albania': 680, 'Albanian': 790, 'Albanians': 905, 'Alcibiades': 993, 'Alden': 484, 'Algeria': 693} 

largest_prime = None
for string, ascii_sum in result_dict.items():
  if is_prime(ascii_sum):
    if largest_prime is None or ascii_sum > largest_prime:
      largest_prime = ascii_sum

if largest_prime is not None:  
  largest_prime_strings = [string for string, ascii_sum in result_dict.items() if ascii_sum == largest_prime] 
  print("The largest prime:", largest_prime)
  print("Key:", largest_prime_strings)
else:
  print("No prime values")
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: This is a trial division wheel sieve. See also Miller-Rabin for larger numbers

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a dictionary for this as you could just keep track of the largest prime value as you iterate over the file content. However, as there may be some reason for using a dictionary, at least there's no point in storing key/value pairs where the value is not prime.

Therefore:

```
# sympy will need to be installed or implement your own version of isprime()
from sympy import isprime

FILE = "english FILTERED.ALL.txt"

mydict = dict()

with open(FILE) as data:
    for line in map(str.rstrip, data):
         if isprime(v := sum(map(ord, line))):
            mydict[line] = v

if len(mydict) == 0:
    print('No prime values found')
else:
    print(*sorted(mydict.items(), key=lambda e: e[1])[-1], sep=' = ')
```

EDITED: to show largest prime and its associated key

Comment: Presumably he also wants to know which word had the largest prime, so in that case he would still need the dictionary.

Comment: The OP should specify what outcome is required if *none* of the dictionary values are prime.